# You can find all the cities using the expression - arrayName[“cityName”], since its an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Given below is the list of cities in the states of India. You are supposed to complete
the function is given after this list which takes input as state name and sends the output as 
a csv of the first letter of all the cities in that particular state

input - `findCityFunction("Manipur")`

output - `"I,L,M,T"`

explanation - `"Imphal*","Lilong","Mayang Imphal","Thoubal"` have their first letters as `I`, `L`, `M` and `T`.

Comment: `Given below is the list of cities in the states of India` ? can you show how your list looks like ?

Comment: let cityData = {
    "Andaman and Nicobar Islands": [
      "Port Blair*"
    ],}                                                                                                                   
  let findCityFunction = (stateName)=>{
    // start your code here.

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let findCityFunction = (stateName)=>{
    let output=[];
    for(var state in cityData)
    {
        if(state === stateName)
        {
            var cities = cityData[state];
            for(var cityName in cities)
            {
                var aCity = cities[cityName];
                output.push(aCity.charAt(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
};

Answer (score 1):

Given an object containing states and cities, it's fairly simple:

```js
const statesAndCities = {
  "Manipur": ["Imphal","Lilong","Mayang Imphal","Thoubal"]
};

const findCityFunction = name => statesAndCities[name].map(([c]) => c).join(",");

console.log(findCityFunction("Manipur"));
```

Comment: Can you explain why does statesAndCities[name].map(([c]) => c) return the first letter of the cities ?

Comment: @Benjamin here it is destructuing only first index value of string, it is same as `let [a] = 'Some string'`